# How to map data using Mongoose Multiple Schema? I need to do this dynamically? Does anyone have an example?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I need to implement a code which supports mapping of data from mongoose routing it to mongodb and node js. I need that to be dynamic in nature so that it supports the REST calls.

Comment: This is too broad. Please be more specific and add the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to your query. I have the code that will help you.
You can check it's tutorial from here: [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3yo2TF4i08)
OR Download the code directly from here: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ProlificsPanther/Samples/releases/tag/MongooseMultipleSchemav1.0)
It'll work without Panther too, you just need to make the mapping correct.

For starters:-

```
var ProfileDataSchema = new Schema({
  hobby: {type: String},
  graduate: {type: String},
  webseries: {type: String},
  tvseries: {type: String},
  name: {type: String, unique: true},
  gaming: {type: String},
  movie: {type: String}
}, {collection: 'profile-data'});

var ProfileData = mongoose.model('ProfileData', ProfileDataSchema);
ProfileDataSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

app.use(session({secret:'mysession',resave:false,saveUninitialized:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.get('/login_router_get', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
  });

  router.post('/login_router_post', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('IN POST');
  var user_name = req.session.user_name;
              var passwordtxt = req.session.passwordtxt;
              console.log('IN LOGIN ROUTER POST SESSION VALUE'+req.session.user_name);
              request({

              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://10.0.10.176:9080/PEGServer/subhan.lib/login_session/get_data', 
              async: false,
              data: { user_name : user_name, passwordtxt : passwordtxt }, 
              dataType: 'json'

              },
               function(err, res, body){
              var json = JSON.parse(body);
              console.log(json+"in ajax call");
              console.log(json.name);
              var item = json;
               //var item ={body};

console.log(item);
console.log('Item inserted');

  var data = new ProfileData(item);
  data.save();

});
res.json(user_name);
    });
```

Comment: Answers with just links will become invalid when the external link is removed/changed. You should post your answer with details here and provide additional links

Comment: I added the links just because there's complete detail on YouTube and GitHub links that I have shared but I won't from now.